# sum all value in stock(qty) and then join and sum all value of customer(qty) table and show into another column as available_stock

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

### sum function results incorrect(when joining two tables) ##

```
select dress,sum(qty) as sold 
 from customer group by dress
-----------------------
Dress         |  Sold |
Casual Dress  |  5    |
Fancy Dress   |  2    |
Jeans         |  3    |
-----------------------
```

- correct Result

```
select dress,sum(qty) as stock 
from stock group by dress
-----------------------
Dress         |  Stock |
Casual Dress  |  15    |
Fancy Dress   |  17    |
Jeans         |  35    |
Party Wear    |  15    |
-----------------------
```

- ***correct result***

### joining both tables

```
    select s.Id ,s.dress, sum(s.qty) 
    as stock, sum(c.qty) as sold,
    sum(s.qty-c.qty) as available
    from stock s
    left outer join customer c
    on c.Id=s.Id group by s.dress,s.Id

----------------------------------------------
Id  Dress        | Stock | Sold | available  |
1   Fancy Dress  | 17    | 6    | 11         | 
2   Casual Dress | 30    | 10   | 20         |
3   Party Wear   | 15    | NULL | NULL       |
4   Jeans        | 35    | 18   | 17         |
----------------------------------------------
```

**incorrect result when joining both of above table**

Comment: Any one please solve it

Comment: Start with reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then update your question.

Comment: What **sql** do you use ? MySQL  ? Oracle SQL ? somethng else ? ..

Comment: sql server management studio 2008

Comment: can you output the ID in the two first queries ? Are they realy corresponding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your case with your data (according the 2 correct query result) but nothing wrong happened

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/4208

I suspect you have different id for the same product on each table, so you can try to join your table on dress( the name) instead of ids

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a better database design, using a product table with productId and productName. But, based on what you supplied

```
create table #customer
(
    customerId      int
    ,dressName      varchar(20)
    ,qtySold        int
)

create table #dress
(
    dressId     int 
    ,dressName  varchar(20)
    ,qtyInStock int
)

insert into #customer
select 1,'Casual Dress',5 union all
select 1,'Casual Dress',5 union all
select 1,'Fancy Dress',2 union all
select 2,'Jeans',3

insert into #dress
select 1,'Casual Dress',15 union all
select 2,'Fancy Dress',17 union all
select 3,'Jeans',35 union all
select 4,'Casual Dress',15 union all
select 5,'Party Wear',15 

select * from #customer
select * from #dress

select t2.dressName, t2.stock, t1.sold, (t2.stock - t1.sold) as available 
from
    (select dressName, sum(qtySold) as sold
     from #customer
     group by dressName) t1
     right join (select dressName, sum(qtyInStock) as stock
            from #dress
            group by dressName) t2 on t1.dressName = t2.dressName


 drop table #customer
 drop table #dress
```

ouptput:

```
dressName       stock   sold    available
Casual Dress    30      10      20
Fancy Dress     17      2       15
Jeans           35      3       32
Party Wear      15      NULL    NULL
```